# What official source details what an Empire citizen knows of WFRP's monsters?

Tags: wfrp-2e, wfrp-1e, warhammer, wfrp

Skaven are bogeymen nobody truly believes in, even though the existence of Beastmen are widely accepted. Unofficial sources seem to say it's mostly because Skaven are highly organized and technical, whereas Beastmen are terrible but rather stupid, barbaric creatures of Chaos.

**What official source (sourcebook, website, etc) details comprehensively what an average Empire citizen knows and/or believes of WFRP's monsters?**

It's not monster stats — a simple bestiary — I'm looking for. I'm looking for an official source on fluff dealing with in-game people's in-game views.

For the sake of this question let's assume the only books I have are the core books for WFRP1 and WFRP2, but I'm open to sources from any edition including sourcebooks for the strategy game or system-agnostic, world-building publications sanctioned by GW at some point in time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yet, the book you are looking for is exactly the [Old World Bestiary](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/62848/Warhammer-Fantasy-Roleplay-2nd-Edition-Old-World-Bestiary).

For every creature in the book, we are given a few flavor texts written by common folk (*Common View*), scholars (*Scholar's Eye*) and comments from the race/creature in question when possible (*Our Own View*). Over half of the book are those comments, with a classical bestiary with stats at the last half of the book.

And yes, that includes a comment with *"Uuhhhhh!"* from a mindless zombie.